# Use defined keys in Info.plist within code as constants

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constants, info.plist

in iOS - 14, I am using these keys shown in photo as purposekeys in info.plist file.

I am accessing them in code as below,

```
    if let accuracyStatus = locationManager?.accuracyAuthorization {
        if(accuracyStatus == .reducedAccuracy) {
            locationManager?.requestTemporaryFullAccuracyAuthorization(withPurposeKey: "AccuracyFeatureFirst", completion: { (error) in
                print("error -> \(error.debugDescription)")
            })
        }
    }
```

**Issue:-**

In the code above, I don't want to use "Magic string" as "AccuracyFeatureFirst" rather I want to fetch it with some constant. is there any good way to do that in swift?

[image]

Comment: You can of course create a constant and there are many ways to do that, globally, locally, in an enum ... but I think the most important thing is to add some unit test to make sure you have spelled it correctly. Regarding the string, if you are only using it in one place then I would create the constant locally close to where it is used.

Comment: I want to use these keys in code. Don't I need to parse it somehow and use it in the code? @JoakimDanielson